# To limit number of items to be displayed in react predictive input

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native

Implementing React from couple of months. I used '[react-predictive-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-predictive-input)' for predicting items from the pre-defined list on **onchange** event.

With "large" data sets (500/1000 items) the AutoComplete component becomes very slow especially when typing the first 3 characters because it will render many items in the dropdown slowing the entire interface, even using a maxHeight for the component.

Do we have any attribute as 'max-items' to show from the list?

Below is the snippet of code :

```
 <Autocomplete
         id="items"
         placeholder="My Items"
         data={this.props.items}
         onSelected={this.onItemSelected.bind(this)} />
```

Function is invoked if item is selected

```
 onItemSelected(value){
         console.log(`${value} was selected`);
     }
```

List of items

```
static defaultProps = {
  items:[
   'car','Bicycle','Truck','Green Van'............................1000items]
};
```

Text prediction works fine, speed and display are becoming an issue to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Material UI Autocomplete for retrieving the use cases mentioned in the question. Link for reference [here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/auto-complete).